# Outlook 2010 Customize Design of Message Header in both Reading Pane and Open Message Window

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am developing an Oulook 2010 Addin with Visual Studio 2013.

I need to design the Mail Message Header in both the "Open Mail Window" and the "Reading Pane". 
I tried using "Design A Form" within Outlook BUT:
a) Many of the default controls are missing. For example: Flag, Importance, Image of Sender etc.
b) There is no option to design the Reading Pane.

Can anyone help?
Is there any other way to achieve this?

How can I make a minor design change to the form while keeping all the original controls and functionality in tact?

Answer (score 0):

Custom forms don't support the Reading pane. Instead, you may consider developing an Outlook add-in with a Form region. See [Creating Outlook Form Regions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386301.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information. For example, you may use the Adjoining form region type. But you can't place the form at the top of the window.

Also you may consider using [Advanced form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php) from Add-in Express. They provide the layout at the top. Or just use Windows API functions for subclassing Outlook windows. See [Creating Adjacent Windows In Outlook](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/OlAdjacentWindows/) for the sample code.